# mercurial merge abort 3 heads

Tags: merge, mercurial, head, abort

Hello i have read some questions but it 's still not clear

```
hg merge
abort: branch 'REL1' has 3 heads - please merge with an explicit rev

changeset:   5337:2471f5588ebc
branch:      REL1   
tag          tip 
date:        26 aout

changeset:   5325:97ad4693f9f6
branch:      REL1
date:        10 mars

changeset:   4756:403f6cc6a294
branch:      REL1H
parent:      4752:30cc28d10501
parent:      4755:747a1722622b
date:        Mon Oct 10 14:14:17 2011 +0200
summary:     merge
```

The 3 heads have the same name How to merge?

I try, i am on the most earliest

```
hg merge 5325 or hg merge 4756
abort: outstanding uncommitted changes
```

Although when i do hg status i have only
    ! aaaa
    ? ddddd
I don't now how to clean this
I have done commit but i cant push

```
hg push
searching for changes
abort: push creates new remote branches: REL5308_64!

I dont know why it display a branch REL5308_64
```

I am desperate

Answer (score 4):

First things first, you need a clean working directory to be able to merge, i. e. your working directory is exactly the changeset to get the merge, with no uncommitted changes. So you can one of:

- Commit these changes `$ hg commit -m 'Your comment'`
- Or discard uncommitted changes with [update](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#update) `$ hg update -C`

Once it's clean you can [merge](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#merge) by pairs.

```
$ hg merge 5325
$ hg commit -m 'merge'
$ hg merge 4756
$ hg commit -m 'merge'
```

And finally [push](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#push).

P.S.- See your work with [log](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#log) `$ hg log -G -l 10 -T "{rev} {desc}" -r "branch(REL1)"`